# Mover elemento existente al lado de otro

Tags: javascript, css, api, dom

Buenos días y gracias de antemano.
Tengo una APP que obtiene de una API 30 post de redes sociales.
Entre sus funcionalidades está la de ver los votos de cada post y quienes han votado.
Esta información la muestro en una ventana modal, que ya tengo posicionada en un DIV.
El problema es: Que si quiero ver los votos de una publicación inferior, la ventana sigue abriéndose arriba ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar el div de la ventana y posicionarlo al lado de cada elemento clicado?

Código:

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <h1 id="titulo">Top post 2021</h1>
    <div id="contenedor-modal" class="contenedor_modal">
        <div class="ventanaModal" id="ventanaModal">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contenedorPost">


    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**script.js**

```
const CONTENEDOR = document.getElementById('contenedorPost');
const VOTOS_URL = 'https://restnodejs-posts.herokuapp.com/api/top_posts/votes/';
const VENTANA_MODAL = document.getElementById('ventanaModal');

const verVotos = async (id) => {
    try {
        const pregunta = await fetch(VOTOS_URL + id);

        if (pregunta.status === 200) {
            // let ventanaModal = document.getElementById("ventanaModal");

            const datos = await pregunta.json();
            // console.log(datos);

            VENTANA_MODAL.innerHTML = `
            <div class="modalVotos">
            <div>Post numero: ${id}</div>
                <div>Número de votos: ${datos.length}</div>
            </div>
            <div>Usuarios que han votado: </div>
        `;
        let elementoClick = document.getElementById(id);
        elementoClick.appendChild(VENTANA_MODAL);
            let votantes = {};

            datos.forEach(function (datos) {
                votantes[datos.voter] = (votantes[datos.voter] || 0) + 1;
            });
            for (let voto in votantes) {
                VENTANA_MODAL.innerHTML += `<div>${voto} : ${votantes[voto]}</div>`;

            }
            VENTANA_MODAL.style.display = "block";

            setTimeout(() => {
                VENTANA_MODAL.style.display = 'none';
            }, 3000);

        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

}
```

El contenedorPost no sé si es necesario ya que cada post de dentro tiene su propio id que es el paremetro que le paso a `verVotos = async (id) => {}`
Una vez tengo el elemento, me gustaría desplegar la ventana modal al lado de dicho elemento.

Añado mi **estilo.css** por si fuera fallo de diseño

```
#contenedor {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}



.post {
    background-color: #85929E;
    color: white;
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;

    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;

}

#contenedor .post {
    margin: 30px;
    min-width: 20vw;
    /*max-width: 25vw;*/
    /*height: 25vh;*/
    padding: 35px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    background-color: #85929E;
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-radius: 6px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;

}

#ventanaModal {
    color: black;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -130px 0 0 -190px;
    /* visibility: hidden; */
    opacity: 100;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: En elelementoClick estás llamando al id, y si estoy leyendo bien tu código, el id es ventanaModal. Por lo que cada vez que clickeas, se muestra el contenido con id="ventanaModal". Para corregir eso deberías agregar un id dinámico, con un contador de elementos que diga cuantos posts hay y que los liste, y tomas ese número y se lo agregas al id. No publico la respuesta porque soy nuevo en esto de responder y no sé si está bien :v

Comment: Muchas gracias Nicolás, probaré lo que me has dicho. Un saludo.